# resize page and crop div - CSS or JS

Tags: html, image, background, crop

I've a problem with an HTML page. This page has 2 elements:

- 1 `div` with `position: absolute` in the left part of the page that is a logo of the page
- 1 `table` always at the center of the page.

If I resize the page, the table is always at the center of the page, but I'd want that the div crops the background in this mode:

[image]

How can I do this trick?

The css of the left div is :

```
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
width:40%;
height : 100%;
background-image : url('img.png');
background-size : contain;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
background-position:fixed;
resize: none;
overflow: none;
```

Comment: Thanks :) I added some code, just the CSS of the DIV

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background-position:fixed for the logo.

Comment: Nothing ... the div that contains the background is :
position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 width:40%;
 height : 100%;
background-image : url('../immagine.jpg');
 background-size : contain;
 background-repeat : no-repeat;
 background-position:fixed;
 resize: none;
    overflow: none;

Answer (score 0):

You can do the image cropping by giving a negative value as the left div's left coordinate, using `calc()`, like:

```
left:calc(35% - 400px);
```

Where 35% is the horizontal point where you want to crop the image, and 400px is the left div's width.

```css
#cendiv{position:absolute;
width:30%;
height: 20%;
background-color: yellow ;
left:35%;
top:40%;
}

#leftdiv {position: absolute ;
width:400px;
left:calc(35% - 400px);
top:0 px;
}

#leftdiv img {
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cendiv"></div>

<div id="leftdiv">

<img src="http://www.freeimages.com/assets/182924/1829230933/leaf-collection-1-895724-m.jpg"> 

</div>
```